# Bootstrap 3 Datepicker - Knockout.js

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, datepicker

Has anyone used, with success, the [Bootstrap 3 Datepicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) together with knockout.js?

I was spending my afternoon on datepickers and knockout.js bindingHandlers, but with no success.

Here is my current knockout.bindingHandler:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.datepicker = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        //when a user changes the date, update the view model
        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "changeDate", function (event) {
            var value = valueAccessor();
            if (ko.isObservable(value)) {
                value(event.date);
            }
        });
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var widget = $(element).data("DateTimePicker");
        if (widget) {
            widget.date = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
            widget.setValue();
        }
    }
};
```

And here is my viewModel:

```
function TurbineHistoryViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.severity1 = ko.observable(1);
    self.severity2 = ko.observable(2);
    self.severity3 = ko.observable(3);
    self.severity4 = ko.observable(4);
    self.severity6 = ko.observable(6);

    self.fromDate = new ko.observable(new Date());
    self.toDate = new ko.observable(new Date());
}
```

... and here is my markup:

```html
<div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
    <input type='text' class="form-control" data-bind="datepicker: objVM.fromDate"/>
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
</div>
```

If anyone has a working example of a good datepicker and knockout.js, I will be very keen to hear about it.

Comment: Show your attempts so far, maybe you're on the right track already.

Comment: I get your point, but the problem is that I'm missing the straight connection  beween a datepicker and corresponding knockout.bindinghandler.

I can see that the view calls the bindinghandler, but fails for some reason.

Comment: Yes, but to find out why that is we would need to see the code, don't you think? ;)

Comment: Ideal would be if you built a test setup right here inside your question (click the "snippet" button), with all the libraries in place and working so that the plumbing is out of the way.

Comment: Hmm, they even have a full-blown example regarding Knockout on their documentation page, did you see that? http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Installing/

Comment: Yes - thanks - just found it 10 mins. ago, but still says that...

var picker = $(element).data("DateTimePicker"); is null....

Comment: I don't see you caling `$(element).datetimepicker(options);` in your `init` function. I suspect you still don't do that.

Comment: Thanks - Tomalak - Now it works - I have an issue with the dateformat, but at least the binding is working properly.

Thanks :-)

Comment: Welcome to our latest installment of the popular series "How you save an afternoon by reading the documentation" ;-)

Comment: Please, add your own answer, and mark is as good answer, or fully delete this question that no longer makes sense. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to use the Bootstrap DatePicker 3 knockout bindinghandler found here:

[Bootstrap Datetimepicker installation in Knockout JS](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Installing/#knockout)

and then setup locale and date-format in the options:

```
var options = allBindingsAccessor().dateTimePickerOptions || { locale: 'da', format: 'DD-MM-YYYY' };
$(element).datetimepicker(options);
```

Then use this bindinghandler in the HTML markup:

```
<div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
    <input type='text' class="form-control" data-bind="dateTimePicker: objVM.fromDate"/>
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
</div>
```